# Showing data from firebase in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having problems showing my data from controller to view in ionic angularjs
this is my code

**alkitab.html**

```
 <ion-view view-title="Alkitab ">
    <ion-content class='has-header' style="padding:2%;" ng-init="loadbiblelist();">
        <ion-list>


            <div ng-repeat= "data in alkitabdate" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center; ">
           <h4>{{data.tanggal}}</h4>
           <br>
            <h4>{{data.alkitabs.judulPasal}}</h4>
            <br>
            <div class="isialkitab" style="line-height:2em; font-size:18px; font-family:Roboto; text-align: justify; -moz-text-align-last: center; text-align-last: left;">
                {{data.alkitabs.isi}}
            </div>

            </div>
        </ion-list>
         <button class="button-balanced button-block large-button ion-thumbsup" ng-click="submit()"><h4>Saya Sudah Baca Alkitab</h4></button>
    </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('AlkitabCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Alkitabdetail', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $state, $stateParams, Alkitabdetail) {
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://ayobacaalkitab.firebaseio.com/');
    var childAlkitab = rootRef.child('alkitab');
    var alkitabId = $stateParams.alkitabId;
    console.log(alkitabId);   
    var bibleidurl = childAlkitab.child(alkitabId);

    $scope.loadbiblelist = function() {

    bibleidurl.on('value', function(snapshot){
      $timeout(function(){

      var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();

      $scope.alkitabdate=snapshotVal;
      console.log($scope.alkitabdate);

      });
    });
  }


}])
```

the problem is in console.log($scope.alkitabdate) i can see the result from firebase but it not showing when i try it using ionic serve.

[image]

any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: is it an array that you get from firebase? show us the result

Comment: @Sajeetharan I update it with the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is returning result is an object not an array, so you cannot use ng-repeat over an object, what you can do is,

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center; ">
<h4>{{alkitabdate.tanggal}}</h4>
<br>
 <h4>{{alkitabdate.alkitabs.judulPasal}}</h4>
 <br>
 <div class="isialkitab" style="line-height:2em; font-size:18px; font-family:Roboto; text-align: justify; -moz-text-align-last: center; text-align-last: left;">
 {{alkitabdate.alkitabs.isi}}
 </div>
```

if your result contains more than one object(i.e array) the code which you have should work.